# Windows Phone 7: No way to get downloaded data incrementally from WebClient?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient

In my app I am downloading some MP3s from the Internet using `WebClient`. I use the event `WebClient.OpenReadCompleted` to get notified when the download has completed. This works fine, but...

After the download has finished I need to save the MP3 into IsolatedStorage and this is unbelievable slow on the Windows Phone as there can be up to 50 MB to save.

I tried to look for a way to incrementally receive data to my app as its being downloaded from the web and store it right away to the IsolatedStorage. But I could not find a way to do this with `WebClient`.

Did I miss something, or how can I incrementally get the downloaded bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible with the WebClient, but you can save to file to the Isolated Storage asynchronously not blocking the UI.

If your files are up to 50 MB, you should use Background File Transfer instead of WebClient

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I am saving the file in a thread so that's not the problem. But I will definitely look into Background File Transfer. Sounds more like what I need anyway. :)